# How to compress or hide the processors at top of htop on large machines?

Tags: multi-core, htop

I like to use htop to show me how the server is being used.

Unfortunately with modern servers, the machine might have 48 or even 120 cores. This means that
I can only see the first few lines of htop and never the second half of the htop display that
shows which processes are using the machine.

How can I hide all of the core-usage lines or even better aggregate them for some sort of statistic?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Open the setup screen using <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. The first page of that screen is dedicated to configuring header meters, so you can remove "CPUs" and add "CPU average".

In recent htop versions, there also are "CPUs (1&2/4)" and "CPUs (3&4/4)" meters showing two cores per line, though this is more of use on 8–32 core systems.

To save two more lines, open the "Display options" page and turn off "Leave a margin around header".

Comment: Doesn't work. On a smaller machine it works. A configuration page pops up under the CPU usage bars. But on the bigger machines it doesn't appear because the CPU usage bars take up all of the screen... Any other idea? (And yes, it took me 2 hours to figure out why nothing changed when pressing F2)

Comment: Workaround 1: blindly, hit F2, then right arrow, then DEL. Workaround 2: shrink the font on your terminal to a ridiculously small value, then hit F2 and you should see a barely readable menu.

Comment: Just as an addition, if your terminal doesn't respond to `F2` in ssh. You can use `F2` to edit htop in your **local machine**. And diff the config file(`~/.config/htop/htoprc`) before and after change. Then apply the diff to your remote machine.

Comment: Following up on the non-local-machine comment above, you can hit ESC instead of F10 to get out of setup.

Answer (score 48):

Based on [grawity](https://superuser.com/a/806619/101413)'s answer, you can create a configuration that you like on a different machine and then copy it to the machine where the problem occurs.

The configuration is saved (under Debian) under `~/.config/htop/htoprc`.

1. On a machine where you can see past the header:
2. Press `F2` to get into the configuration.
3. Move left to the "Left Column"
4. Move down to select "CPU" and press F9 to delete it.
5. From the right most column select "CPU Average" and press F5 to insert it instead.
6. F10 let's you leave the menu.
7. copy `~/.config/htop/htoprc` to the larger machine.

In my case (120 cores) a configuration with "CPUs (1&2/4)" on the left side of the header, and "CPUs (3&4/4)" on the right side of the header looks good. As a result, the header takes
up about half the screen and the other half lists the processes. Each line in the header shows four CPUs which is fine for me.

Sample configuration:

```
# Beware! This file is rewritten by htop when settings are changed in the interface.
# The parser is also very primitive, and not human-friendly.
fields=0 48 17 18 38 39 40 2 46 47 49 1 
sort_key=46
sort_direction=1
hide_threads=0
hide_kernel_threads=1
hide_userland_threads=0
shadow_other_users=0
show_thread_names=0
highlight_base_name=0
highlight_megabytes=1
highlight_threads=0
tree_view=0
header_margin=1
detailed_cpu_time=0
cpu_count_from_zero=0
color_scheme=0
delay=15
left_meters=Memory Swap CPU Load LoadAverage 
left_meter_modes=1 1 1 1 1 
right_meters=Tasks LoadAverage Uptime 
right_meter_modes=2 2 2
```

#Alternative (Blind navigation)
Press `F2`, `left`, `F9`. (If CPUs are the items in the header.) After this you can see what is going on and would continue by pressing `F10` to quit the configuration.

## Blind Navigation v2 (2020-07)

Thanks to [islandman93](https://superuser.com/users/1201203/islandman93):

> New blind navigation: `F2`, `right`, `delete`, `right`, `delete`. Then you probably want to add cpu average to the left column

Comment: Blind navigation worked perfectly!

Comment: New blind navigation: `F2`, `right`, `delete`, `right`, `delete`.
Then you probably want to add cpu average to the left column

Comment: Just for who is interested what items changes after modifying CPU. They are `right_meters`, `right_meters` and corresponding `left_meter_modes`, `right_meter_modes`.

Comment: And for anyone using MacOs, you do `Fn+delete` not `delete`

Comment: How do I add cpu average to left column?

Answer (score -3):

Try the 't' key.

None of the other answers helped. My top and terminal must be different. My top was installed via the procps-3.2.8-45.0.1.el6_9.1.x86_64 package on Oracle Enterprise Linux (repackaged RedHat Enterprise Linux) 6.9 and I was accessing it via PuTTY 0.62.

Comment: Well the thread is about htop, not top.

Answer (score -3):

I just had this issue as well, system has 24 cores, boatloads of disks and interfaces, and I couldn't read the process data after all the mem/disk/net lines etc..

Simply starting it differently was the easiest solution:

```
atop -l
```

From the man page:
Limit the number of system level lines for the counters per-cpu, the active disks and the network interfaces.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score -3):

SuSE   : Press F2, Press F10, press q,  sed -i 's/AllCPUs/CPU/g' ~/.htoprc

debian : Press F2, Press F10, press q,  sed -i 's/AllCPUs/CPU/g' ~/.config/htop/htoprc